# ActiveRecord, has_many :through, and Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

Folks,

Want to make sure I understand this correctly. And please disregard the case for inheritance here (SentientBeing), trying to instead focus on polymorphic models in has_many :through relationships. That said, consider the following...

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widget_groupings

  has_many :people, :through => :widget_groupings, :source => :person, :conditions => "widget_groupings.grouper_type = 'Person'"
  has_many :aliens, :through => :widget_groupings, :source => :alien, :conditions => "video_groupings.grouper_type = 'Alien'"
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widget_groupings, :as => grouper
  has_many :widgets, :through => :widget_groupings
end

class Alien < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widget_groupings, :as => grouper
  has_many :widgets, :through => :widget_groupings  
end

class WidgetGrouping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :widget
  belongs_to :grouper, :polymorphic => true
end
```

In a perfect world, I'd like to, given a Widget and a Person, do something like:

```
widget.people << my_person
```

However, when I do this, I've noticed the 'type' of the 'grouper' is always null in widget_groupings. However, if I to something like the following:

```
widget.widget_groupings << WidgetGrouping.new({:widget => self, :person => my_person})
```

Then all works as I would have normally expected. I don't think I've ever seen this occur with non polymorphic associations and just wanted to know if this was something specific to this use case or if I'm potentially staring at a bug.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 163, accepted):

**There is a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3271) with Rails 3.1.1 that breaks this functionality. If you are having this problem first try upgrading, it's been fixed in 3.1.2**

You're so close. The problem is you're misusing the :source option. :source should points to the polymorphic belongs_to relationship. Then all you need to do is specify :source_type for the relationship you're trying to define.

This fix to the Widget model should allow you do exactly what you're looking for.

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widget_groupings

  has_many :people, :through => :widget_groupings, :source => :grouper, :source_type => 'Person'
  has_many :aliens, :through => :widget_groupings, :source => :grouper, :source_type => 'Alien'
end
```

Comment: Oh my god that is so painfully obvious I cannot believe I glazed right over it. Thanks EmFi!

Comment: No problem, I think I agonized for about a day over how to do this the first time I encountered it. Didn't help that it was one of the first things I tried to do in Rails that didn't involve following a tutorial/book.

Comment: As scotkf points out, there is a regression in ActiveRecord 3.1.1 that blocks this behaviour. Upgrading to 3.1.2 will allow this solution to work.

Comment: is it true that I can change source fields to just :as => :grouper

Comment: Same thing as what @Shtirlic mentioned. Is there a way to not specify source_type, so you have a mixed results set? If anyone solved this, would love to know how.

Comment: I keep getting "Unknown primary key for table 'jointable' in model 'Jointable'"... same code as above.

Comment: @DonatoAzevedo: Does your migration define a primary key for that join table?

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Still works as of Rails 4.2.0. However, is there any way to accomplish this these days without source_type and two separate associations?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, this doesn't work with rails 3.1.1 due to a bug on :source, but it's fixed in Rails 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

For example: `locations` have many `trains`, `copters`, `trucks`, `ships`. And `trains`, `copters`, `trucks`, `ships` have many `locations`.

Different `locations` can have similar transports(store in `moveable` polymorphic columns).

```
#db/migrations/create_moveable_locations.rb

class CreateMoveableLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :moveable_locations do |t|
      t.references :moveable, polymorphic: true
      t.references :location

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

#app/models/moveable_location.rb

class MoveableLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :moveable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :location
end

#app/models/location.rb

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :moveable_locations, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :trains, through: :moveable_locations, source: :moveable, source_type: 'Train'
  has_many :copters, through: :moveable_locations, source: :moveable, source_type: 'Copter'
  has_many :trucks, through: :moveable_locations, source: :moveable, source_type: 'Truck'
  has_many :ships, through: :moveable_locations, source: :moveable, source_type: 'Ship'
end

#app/models/train.rb

class Train < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :moveable_locations, as: :moveable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :locations, through: :moveable_locations
end

#app/models/copter.rb

class Copter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :moveable_locations, as: :moveable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :locations, through: :moveable_locations
end

#app/models/truck.rb

class Truck < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :moveable_locations, as: :moveable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :locations, through: :moveable_locations
end

#app/models/ship.rb

class Ship < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :moveable_locations, as: :moveable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :locations, through: :moveable_locations
end
```

Using:

```
train1 = Train.create(title: 'Train1')
train2 = Train.create(title: 'Train2')
location1 = Location.create(title: 'Location1', train_ids: [train1.id, train2.id])
location2 = Location.create(title: 'Location2', trains: [train1, train2])
location3 = Location.create(title: 'Location3')
location3.train_ids << [train1., train2.id]
location4 = Location.create(title: 'Location34')
location4.trains << [train1, train2]
copter1 = Copter.create(title: 'Copter1', location_ids: [location1.id, location2.id]
copter2 = Copter.create(title: 'Copter1')
copter2.location_ids << [location1.id, location2.id, location3.id]
```

Answer (score -4):

has many :through and polymorphic don't work together. If you try to access them directly, it should throw an error.
If i am not mistaken, you have to hand write widget.people and the push routine.

I don't think it is a bug, it is just something which hasn't been implemented yet. I would imagine we see it in the feature, because everyone has a case in which they could use it.

Comment: They do work together. For example:
   has_many :subscriptions, :as => :subscribable
   has_many :subscribers, :through => :subscriptions, :source => :user

Comment: I will throw up an example of my failing code as a separate post in the near future :) It would save me alot of headache to figure out how to bypass that error.