# Rails polymorphic has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I'm pulling some data from an external API and would like to cache the results locally. I have a `class SearchTerm`, which I would like to be associated with a few different ActiveRecord types through the table `searchable_items`. I'm pretty sure I have the tables set up correctly, but something in my associations must be wrong.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :search_terms, :as => :searchable, :through => :searchable_items
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :search_terms, :as => :searchable, :through => :searchable_items
end

class SearchTerm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :searchables, :through => :searchable_items
end

class SearchableItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :search_term
  belongs_to :searchable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I would expect to be able to do something like `SearchTerm.find_by_term('SearchTerm').searchables` (and it would return an array of Foo and Bar objects) however, I get the error 
`Could not find the association :searchable_items in model SearchTerm`

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide to me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add `has_many :searchable_items` association to `Foo`, `Bar` and `SearchTerm` models because `:through => :searchable_items` option refers to that association.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Comment: Unfortunately, adding what you suggested gives `Cannot have a has_many :through association 'SearchTerm#searchables' on the polymorphic object 'Searchable#searchable'.`

Comment: Similar setup here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683265/activerecord-has-many-through-and-polymorphic-associations

Comment: Like the error message says, you cannot have has many through association on polymorpic object. You could have separate has many throughs for `Foo` and `Bar` like in the linked question above.

Comment: The linked question is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Heikki.