# Rails HABTM with polymorphic relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a table `Category` which can have many `Businesses` and `Posts`.  And a `Business`/`Post` can have many `Categories` so I created a polymorphic tabled called `CategoryRelationship` to break up the many to many relationship.

`Business` model has these relationships:

```
  has_many :categories, through: :category_relationships, :source => :category_relationshipable, :source_type => 'Business'
  has_many :category_relationships
```

`CategoryRelationship` model has these relationships:

```
 attr_accessible :category_id, :category_relationship_id, :category_relationship_type

  belongs_to :category_relationshipable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :business
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category
```

`Category` has these relationships:

```
has_many :category_relationships
  has_many :businesses, through: :category_relationships
  has_many :posts, through: :category_relationships
```

`Post` would have similar relationships as `Business`.

So now when I run `Business.first.categories` I get the error:

```
Business Load (6.1ms)  SELECT "businesses".* FROM "businesses" LIMIT 1
  Business Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "businesses".* FROM "businesses" INNER JOIN "category_relationships" ON "businesses"."id" = "category_relationships"."category_relationshipable_id" WHERE "category_relationships"."business_id" = 3 AND "category_relationships"."category_relationshipable_type" = 'Business'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column category_relationships.business_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...lationships"."category_relationshipable_id" WHERE "category_...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "businesses".* FROM "businesses" INNER JOIN "category_relationships" ON "businesses"."id" = "category_relationships"."category_relationshipable_id" WHERE "category_relationships"."business_id" = 3 AND "category_relationships"."category_relationshipable_type" = 'Business'
```

How do I structure the relationships so this works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord, has\_many :through, and Polymorphic Associations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683265/activerecord-has-many-through-and-polymorphic-associations)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Similar questions here: [Rails polymorphic has_many :through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641500/rails-polymorphic-has-many-through)
And here: [ActiveRecord, has_many :through, and Polymorphic Associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683265/activerecord-has-many-through-and-polymorphic-associations)

I think it should be something like this:

```
class Category
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :businesses, through: :categorizations, source: :categorizable, source_type: 'Business'
  has_many :posts, through: :categorizations, source: :categorizable, source_type: 'Post'
end

class Categorization
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :categorizable, polymorphic: true
end

class Business #Post looks the same
  has_many :categorizations, as: :categorizeable
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
end
```

Comment: just curious...why do we need the "has_many :businesses, through: :categorizations...." and "has_many :posts, through: :categorizations..." in the Category model?  Why can't we just have  "has_many :categorizations" ?

Comment: @RavJohal I haven't tested this out, but my thoughts are that you don't actually have to have the last two `has_many` lines in the Category class, but you'd probably want them. All those last two lines do as I understand it is create helper methods on the Category class and allow you to do things like: `@category.businesses` or perhaps `@category.posts.where(published: true)` , etc. Without the last two has_many statements you wouldn't have these helper methods and would have to do something like this: `@category.categorizations.where(categorizable_type: 'Post')......`, basically much harder..