# ActiveRecord, has_many :through, Polymorphic Associations with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In [ActiveRecord, has_many :through, and Polymorphic Associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683265/activerecord-has-many-through-and-polymorphic-associations), the OP's example requests ignoring the possible superclass of `Alien` and `Person` *(`SentientBeing`)*. This is where my question lies.

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widget_groupings

  has_many :people, :through => :widget_groupings, :source => :person, :source_type => 'Person'
  has_many :aliens, :through => :widget_groupings, :source => :alien, :source_type => 'Alien'
end

SentientBeing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widget_groupings, :as => grouper
  has_many :widgets, :through => :widget_groupings
end


class Person < SentientBeing
end

class Alien < SentientBeing
end
```

In this modified example the `grouper_type` value for `Alien` and `Person` are now both stored by Rails as `SentientBeing` *(Rails seeks out the base class for this `grouper_type` value)*.

What is the proper way to modify the `has_many`'s in `Widget` to filter by type in such a case? I want to be able to do `Widget.find(n).people` and `Widget.find(n).aliens`, but currently both of these methods *(`.people` and `.aliens`)* return empty set `[]` because `grouper_type` is always `SentientBeing`.

Comment: This question is very similar to one [I posted earlier][1].

It's an interesting problem because, like you said, the `grouper_type` attribute only stores the superclass.  It seems that what is needed is a join between the widgets and sentient_beings tables.  A more long-winded query like the one I used would probably work for you, but it's not pretty - hence the reason I asked my question.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582588/rails-structuring-a-query-involving-a-polymorphic-association-and-sti

Comment: <3 anonymous down-votes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried the simplest thing - adding `:conditions` to the `has_many :through`s?

In other words, something like this (in widget.rb):

```
has_many :people, :through => :widget_groupings, :conditions => { :type => 'Person' }, :source => :grouper, :source_type => 'SentientBeing'
has_many :aliens, :through => :widget_groupings, :conditions => { :type => 'Alien' }, :source => :grouper, :source_type => 'SentientBeing'
```

JamesDS is correct that a join is needed - but it's not written out here, since the `has_many :through` association is already doing it.