# Retrieve model from polymorphic association via has_many through from STI model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

I want to use **polymorphic association** with a model which derives from a base class using **single table inheritance (STI)**. I already investigated further into this problem and (of course) dug through stackoverflow, e.g. here ([ActiveRecord, has_many :through, and Polymorphic Associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683265/activerecord-has-many-through-and-polymorphic-associations)) and there ([ActiveRecord, has_many :through, Polymorphic Associations with STI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582074/activerecord-has-many-through-polymorphic-associations-with-sti)). Unfortunately all information I found regarded to polymorphic associations but not to the usage in the context of STI.

In my current project I have a design which has one screenshot and many assets linked to it. Some assets (variation assets) should also have screenshots linked to them. Because a design has many assets I want to fetch all screenshots *through* them.

**design.rb**

```
class Design < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :screenshot, as: :screenshotable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :assets, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :screenshots, through: :assets
end
```

**screenshot.rb**

```
class Screenshot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :screenshotable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**asset.rb**

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :design
end
```

**variation_asset.rb**

```
class VariationAsset < Asset
    # this is the important part as only a
    # variation asset should have a screenshot
    has_one :screenshot, as: :screenshotable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Assigning `Screenshot` to `VariationAsset` works well. Trying this with `Asset` raises an `NoMethodError` as expected (and wanted). Hence the polymorphic interface seems to work and was set up correctly in the schema.

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "screenshots", :force => true do |t|
  t.string  "name"
  t.integer "screenshotable_id"
  t.string  "screenshotable_type"
end

create_table "assets", :force => true do |t|
  t.string  "name"
  t.integer "design_id"
  t.string  "type"
end
```

Querying every `Screenshot` from a `Design` through the `Asset` raises the following error:

**active_record/reflection.rb:509:in `check_validity!': Could not find the source association(s) :screenshot or :screenshots in model Asset. Try 'has_many :screenshots, :through => :assets, :source => '. Is it one of :design? (ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError)**

I tried it with the `:source` parameter as suggested in the error message but this also did not help.

It works when I put the `has_one :screenshot, as: :screenshotable, dependent: :destroy` line into the STI base class `Asset`:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :design
  has_one :screenshot, as: :screenshotable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I think it has something to do with the `through:` parameter and the fact that it seems (for me) to be impossible to tell it to look into `VariationAsset` instead of `Asset` somehow.

You find a "working" example of the above code at my [github repo](https://github.com/Partyschaum/active_record_playground/tree/polymorphic_sti).

Any help appreciated! :-)

Comment: Grabbed your repo, but this would all be a *lot* easier with tests/specs. It all runs fine for me, but I have to interpret whether it's supposed to or not.

Comment: AR will always attempt to get the association information via the base class reflection and not inspect its subclasses. Why would you want to make Asset non-screenshotable in the first place?

Comment: So what did you specify as :source? It is obvious that AR is confused, because your HATM relation points to :assets, a model which has no :screenshot association in the first place. It would work if you specified :variable_asset there, but then your Design model doesn't have :variable_asset association.
Your easiest solution would be adding `has_many :variable_assets` to Design model and using `has_many :screenshots, :through => :variable_assets` instead.