# Rails has_many: through: association to a table that uses STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many, single-table-inheritance

I can't figure out how to make this work; I've looked at other SO questions including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582074/activerecord-has-many-through-polymorphic-associations-with-sti) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613983/rails-how-to-make-has-many-through-association-work-with-single-table-inherita) but to no avail.

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connections
  has_many :data_sources, through: :connections
end

class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :data_source
end

class DataSource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connections
  has_many :users, through: :connections
end

class AdNetwork < DataSource
end

class Marketplace < DataSource
end
```

AdNetwork, Marketplace and DataSource all use the same table through STI.

I want to set up associations on `User` called `marketplaces` and `ad_networks` which return all the `data_sources` where `type` is `MarketPlace` or `AdNetwork` respectively. How can I do this?

---

**Things I've tried that didn't work:**

```
class User
  has_many :marketplaces, through: :data_sources # Throws an error
  has_many :marketplaces, through: :connections # Throws an error
  has_many :marketplaces, through: :connections, source: :data_source # Returns ALL data sources, not just Marketplaces
  has_many :marketplaces, { through: :connections, source: :data_source }, -> { where(type: "Marketplace" } # Again this returns ALL data sources. Wtf???
end
```

I also tried adding a column `data_source_type` to `Connection` and adding the following lines

class Connection
  belongs_to :data_source, polymorphic: true
end

class DataSource
  has_many :connections, as: :data_source
end

class User
  has_many :marketplaces, through: :connections, source: :data_source, source_type: "Marketplace"
end

... but now `#marketplaces` returns an empty relation. (It looks like `data_source_type` is ALWAYS being set to `DataSource`, even when I add a Marketplace or an AdNetwork.)

What am I doing wrong?