# Polymorphic has_many: through in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a tags model that I'd like to be polymorphic, but I don't want five records for a tag of "video" for example, I want to create the tag once and be able to use it on a variety of models. I've ready some of the questions here about doing that, but I'm not quite getting how to make it work.

So I've got:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tagable, :polymorphic => true

end
```

and

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :through => :tag_assignments

end
```

and

```
class TagAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :tags, :as => :taggable

end
```

Seems to me that should work, but... reading all the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683265/activerecord-has-many-through-and-polymorphic-associations) here I know I need a `:source =>` option in there somewhere to tie it all together, but I'm just not following exactly how to do it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to redo your models as follows:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_assignments
end

class TagAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tagable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_assignments, :as => :tagable
  has_many :tags, :through => :tag_assignments
end
```

Now given a post you can get its tags as follows:

```
post.tags
```

**Note**

You should consider using the [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem for your use case.

Comment: Okay, so the intermediate table is the polymorphic one. Makes sense.