# Rails belongs_to user but polymorphic has_many model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In a new rails app, I have to build this sort of relationship

```
Trip -> 1-to-1 -> Plan
Plan -> n-to-n -> Places
Plan -> n-to-n -> Activities
```

and ofcourse the vice-versa relationship as well..

The `plan` table is something I'm thinking about. Whether it is possible to have a direct `Trip -> Places` and `Trip -> Activities` relationship without any extra table.

If not, then what could be and efficient way to handle this kind of relationship, keeping in mind that there might be other models which could have a n-to-n relationship with the Plan model in the future.

UPDATE - I found this question and the answer to work. Might be helpful for someone looking to do the same as I am

[ActiveRecord, has_many :through, and Polymorphic Associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683265/activerecord-has-many-through-and-polymorphic-associations)

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but complicated and messy, so I wouldn't.  You can define `has_many ..., :through => :plan` associations to easily and efficiently access the places and activities for trips, etc.

Rails doesn't offer the `:through` option for `belong_to` associations, but you can define convenience methods to access those, and you can query the associated records efficiently by using the `:include` option when finding.

Comment: but won't the has_many :through => :plan require a place_id and activity_id in the plan table ? Wouldn't that be a problem ? I was wondering if I could have a generic x_id & x_type column in the plan table and then setup the has_many :through => :plan association. Would this be possible ?

Comment: @hashpipe With the `:through` => option, ActiveRecord examines the model you are associating through to determine how it is related to the target model. I just tried this to confirm in Rails 3.2.3. I created an `Aaa` model that belongs to `:bbbs`, a `Bbb` model that has and belongs to many `:cccs`, and then set `Aaa` have and belong to many `:cccs` through `:bbb`.  I am then able to execute `Aaa.first.cccs`, and the SQL is `SELECT "cccs".* FROM "cccs" INNER JOIN "bbbs_cccs" ON "cccs"."id" = "bbbs_cccs"."ccc_id" INNER JOIN "bbbs" ON "bbbs_cccs"."bbb_id" = "bbbs"."id" WHERE "bbbs"."id" = 1`