# Ruby on Rails get all comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many, polymorphic-associations

I have a (polymorphic) object `Comment` (which will be used for `Vehicle` and `Review` objects). How can I get all `comments` for `User`'s `Vehicle`s: `@user.vehicles.comments`? It says that method `comments` is undefined for `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Any simple way to get it working? Is it many-to-many relation: many vehicles have many comments? Or am I wrong? `@user.vehicles.first.comments` works properly.

Relationships between objects (not full):

```
User 
has_many Vehicles. 

Vehicle 
belongs_to User. 
has_many Comments (as commentable). 

Comment 
belongs_to Commentable, :polymorphic => true
```

Comment: Could you please add the model code about relationship between User, Vehicle, Comment ?

Comment: User has many Vehicles. Vehicle belongs_to User. Vehicle has many Comments (as commentable). Comment belongs_to Commentable, :polymorphic => true.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this, it will be a lot more readable than in the comment.

Comment: I think you are not getting the vehicle if you use user.vehicles. instead you are getting all the vehicles.

Comment: Of course not. I want to get all comments for all of the Vehicles, belonging to the User.

Comment: The problem is that `@user.vehicles` is a **collection** of vehicles and a collection doesn't have a `comments` method (an object as you pointed out does). `has_many :through` may be an option, but no one has shown how you can do that for both vehicles and reviews. Maybe this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683265/activerecord-has-many-through-and-polymorphic-associations) is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments part of it is just fine. The thing is - you are calling:

```
@user.vehicles.comments
```

Here, the vehicles is a AR relationship object which doesn't know anything about the comments. ie - @user.vehicles is the collection of vehicles for that user.

To get all comments on vehicles linked to the user, you can do this:

```
@user.vehicles.to_a.collect{|v| v.comments.to_a }.flatten
```

Which will return an array of all comments on any of the user's vehicles.

Comment: Yeah. Straightforward solution. I just wanted it to be prettier :))

Comment: For those, who experiece the same problem:

in associated object:

def self.comments
   all.collect { |v| v.comments }.flatten
end

And that's pretty much it. At least it works :)

Comment: @Dmitri glad to help. Actually got me thinking - maybe I'll write this and submit to acts_as_taggable gem. Seems like a fairly  common issue.

Comment: It could be a great support for many of us. :) Also, I've slightly improved your solution, using "includes" command, thanks to "prashantsahni", to get rid of N+1 queries problem. The only thing, that confused me, though, (:include => :comments) didn't work, while includes(:comments) works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Write this in user.rb:

```
    has_many :comments, :through => :vehicles
```

Now do

```
 @user.comments
```

It will fetch all the comments created for your vehicles

you can also fetch comments through:

```
    @user.vehicles(:include => :comments).collect{|v| v.comments}.flatten
```

But this is not the right way, in my opinion.

Comment: 1) I need comments not only for the Vehicles. 
2) It may be wrong, but it works 100% properly. All other solutions don't work

Answer (score 1):

I think you are try doing complex association or maybe you misunderstand about polymorphic association. It's simpler than you think. Here is associtation you should define:

```
User 
has_many vehicles 

Vehicle 
belongs_to user 
has_many comments, as: :commentable

Comment 
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
```

To get all comments of vehicle of your user, you can define a `has_many :through` association in User model:

```
User 
has_many vehicles 
has_many comments, through: :vehicles
```

Now you can use `@user.comments` to get all comments about vehicles of user.

Comment: I need to collect comments for different objects. That's why I have it defined so and not the other way around. Using your approach I will be only gettings comments for Vehicles, and what about other objects ? (Reviews, etc ..)

Comment: Thank you for your support, but I still don't see why would It work. 

I need it to work: user.reviews.comments, @user.vehicles.comments, user.<you name it>.comments. Hm.

Comment: i have no idea now, but maybe this link can help you (or not) [polymorphic has many through](http://www.unixgods.org/~tilo/Rails/Rails_polymprphic_has_many_through_relationships.html)

Comment: Maybe it it will. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

in the user model add :

```
has_many :comments, :through => :vehicles
```

Edit for vehicle and reviews :

In the user model :

```
has_many :comments, :through => :vehicles, :as => :comments_vehicles
has_many :comments, :through => :reviews, :as => :comments_reviews

def comments
  self.comments_vehicles + self.comments_reviews
end
```

Comment: And what about comments for Reviews and other things ?

Comment: You could do a method that returns self.comments_vehicle + self.comments_reviews but i'm not sure if this is the best solution

Comment: Could you update your code and show how to do it for both vehicles and reviews?

Comment: Just did it, tell me if this is ok for you

Comment: I will take a look! ) Just a sec