# Rails has_many through polymorphic source_type scope_chain bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

Ok, some weird stuff has been happening since I set up some polymorphic :through relationships.

I'm using Rails 3.2.12 with Ruby 1.9.3.

The relationships are as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :registrations

has_many :student_learning_component_statuses, :through => :registrations

has_many :programs, :through => :student_learning_component_statuses, :source => :statusable, :source_type => 'Program'
has_many :phases, :through => :student_learning_component_statuses, :source => :statusable, :source_type => 'Phase'
```

Now when I query either a user's programs or phases, whichever I query **first** always succeeds, and the relationship queried **second** returns an empty array.

Console usage results shown below:

```
1.9.3p392 :005 > User.find_by_email('s1@nyfs.com').programs
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 's1@nyfs.com' LIMIT 1
  Program Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" INNER JOIN "student_learning_component_statuses" ON "programs"."id" = "student_learning_component_statuses"."statusable_id" INNER JOIN "registrations" ON "student_learning_component_statuses"."registration_id" = "registrations"."id" WHERE "registrations"."user_id" = 137 AND ("student_learning_component_statuses"."statusable_type" = 'Program')
 => [#<Program id: 1, title: "Beginner Certification", description: "", school_id: 47, created_at: "2013-06-27 19:46:44", updated_at: "2013-06-27 22:13:27", duration: "16 weeks">, #<Program id: 2, title: "Instructor Certification", description: "Another Program to test more stuff", school_id: 47, created_at: "2013-06-28 02:14:43", updated_at: "2013-06-28 02:14:43", duration: "20 weeks">] 
1.9.3p392 :006 > User.find_by_email('s1@nyfs.com').phases
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 's1@nyfs.com' LIMIT 1
  Phase Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "phases".* FROM "phases" INNER JOIN "student_learning_component_statuses" ON "phases"."id" = "student_learning_component_statuses"."statusable_id" INNER JOIN "registrations" ON "student_learning_component_statuses"."registration_id" = "registrations"."id" WHERE "registrations"."user_id" = 137 AND ("student_learning_component_statuses"."statusable_type" = 'Program' AND "student_learning_component_statuses"."statusable_type" = 'Phase')
 => []
```

Note the end of the second query checks that `statusable_type = 'Program' AND statusable_type = 'Phase'`, which will never be the case.  Has anyone encountered an issue like this?  Is it time to upgrade to Rails 4?  Or maybe something is wrong with my relationships.

Please let me know if more code might be useful, and thanks in advance for any suggestions.

#### [Update]

Based on my research, the fix to this issue has still not been integrated as of the Rails 4 master branch, so I will continue deferring the upgrade to Rails 4 for now.

Comment: your user class is extending ActiveRecord::Base i guess?: class User < ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: yep, it is a subclass of ActiveRecord::base

Comment: compared to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683265/activerecord-has-many-through-and-polymorphic-associations?rq=1 the difference i see here is that student_learning_component_statuses is another join model based on registrations wich might be causing the trouble in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this issue, although rare, is known to the rails team:

Issue as described:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3882

Underlying issue:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/10538

A code patch which may potentially provide a fix:
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b644c51c0ad22ff309d9717b7e9a3bfbc856a8c4

Instead of patching the code, I opted to follow the 'hack' outlined in the first link.  For my particular use case the hack is as follows (and I have verified it indeed works):

```
  has_many :_users_programs, :through => :registrations, :source => :student_learning_component_statuses # workaround (do not use directly)
  has_many :programs, :source_type => 'Program', :source => :statusable, :through => :_users_programs

  has_many :_users_phases, :through => :registrations, :source => :student_learning_component_statuses # workaround (do not use directly)
  has_many :phases, :source_type => 'Phase', :source => :statusable, :through => :_users_phases
```