# Multiple has_many relationships to same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model User that can create Posts

```
User
 has_many :posts
Post
 belongs_to :user
```

However, I want to also allow users to save posts as bookmarks. So I added the following:

```
Bookmark
 belongs_to :post
 belongs_to :user
User
 has_many :posts
 has_many :posts, :through => :bookmarks
Post
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :posts, :through => :bookmarks
```

This can't be right because it is now ambiguous when I do @user.posts . Does that refer to the posts the user wrote or the posts the user bookmarked?

How do you get around this problem?

Comment: Little unsure about your question after reading it twice.  The code you've shown is not correct for has_many through association.  Are you saying you want to distinguish between "bookmarked" and "not bookmarked" posts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord, has\_many :through, and Polymorphic Associations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683265/activerecord-has-many-through-and-polymorphic-associations)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> How do you get around this problem?

By giving your associations unique names. It's not that you can't unambiguously access them, it's that your second one is destroying the first one.

Instead of calling both `posts`, use `bookmarked_posts` for your second association and use `source:` to call posts

```
has_many :bookmarked_posts, through: :bookmarks, source: :post
```

Comment: I'm struggling to wrap my head around which foreign keys live where in this scenario.

Comment: @pdoherty926 Everywhere there is a `belongs_to`, there is a foreign key. There is always a one-to-one mapping of `belongs_to` to foreign keys.

Comment: I get an error when I specify `source: :posts`, but `source: :post` works

Comment: `Post` is the `belongs_to` you are accessing. The `belongs_to` will always be singular because of rails naming conventions

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this?

```
User
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :posts, through: :bookmarks
  has_many :authored_posts, foreign_key: :author_id, class_name: 'Post'
Bookmark
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
Post
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :users, through: :bookmarks
```

In this way, you are able to keep posts that are written by and bookmarked by a user separate. You could also set it up so that whenever an author creates a post, it can automatically get bookmarked by the user. i.e.

```
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    @post = @user.authored_posts.build(post_params)
    @user.posts << @post

    if @post.valid?
      # do good stuff
    else
      # do errors
    end
  end
end
```

There is a strong 1:N relationship between author and authored_posts. Then there is a weaker N:M relationship between Users and Posts using Bookmark as the join model. You can add authored posts to be bookmarked when they are created using the controller code above. Removing a bookmark on an authored post will simply remove it from the `posts` relationship, but not the `authored_posts` relationship.

You cannot define multiple relationships using the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to previous comments here but successfully used `inverse_of` to differentiate users and 'post authors':

```
User
has_many :authored_posts, class_name: 'Post', inverse_of: 'author'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [rails API on this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html). You should be able to specify `:as` and `:source`