# Setting up Rails model for bookmarks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have `User` and `Post` models. set up in this way:

```
User
  has_many: :posts
Post
  belongs_to :user
```

I'm trying to add a `Bookmark` model now, so that a single user can bookmark multiple posts.

I'm trying to think of the best way to do this.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690700/multiple-has-many-relationships-to-same-model) thread addressing a has many association on the same model, and the answer says to use `has_many: :through =>` and rename the association, but my main concern is that this makes it insanely confusing to me. I would never say @post.posts, so I don't like having that association even written.

Currently the way I'm doing it is...

```
User
  has_many :posts
  has_many :bookmarks
Bookmark
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
Post
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bookmarks
```

I'm not using `:through`, `:source`, `:as` or any fancy magic.

To me it makes it very clear what the associations are though, without it being overly complicated. Am exact queries or features am I missing out on (any Rails syntactic sugar) by doing it this way, without all that extra magic?

Comment: Per my answer below, I don't think you are missing out on anything. Best thing to do is start building. If you find you need some association that is not there, you can always add it. Just remember to restart your web server (or reload the rails console) when testing, as it needs to reload the models and generate those associations.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the answer. I completely rewrote my question because it was messy but I see what you mean. So you think it's reasonable here not to use through,as or source? I've been trying to do things the rails way ™

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything un-rails-ish here. `has_many, through:` is favored for many - to - many associations in Rails, but that is not really what you have here. You don't really have any two-directional `has_many` relationships. Since the relationship of a User to Posts is not THROUGH Bookmarks, there is no need for that relation. You have three different things that are inter-related.

Comment: It comes down to what `has` means. Users don't own Posts through Bookmarks. They own their own Posts, but Bookmark Posts that may or may not belong to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user has many bookmarks, a bookmark *points* to a single post (another way to think about it), a person's own posts have nothing conceptually to do with their bookmarks, because they may coincide or they may not. I would think Bookmarks table would just be a simple table of

```
| id | user_id | post_id |
```

You may be over thinking it. Yes, it looks like a join table, but really it should also have 'created_at' and 'updated_at':

```
| id | user_id | post_id | created_at | updated_at |
```

A User has_many Bookmarks, and an individual Bookmark belongs_to a User. A Bookmark also belongs_to a Post and a Post (potentially) has_many Bookmarks.

This gives you the method you might want:

```
@user.bookmarks
@post.bookmarks
@bookmark.post
@bookmark.user
@bookmark.post.users
```

That last one gives you all the users that bookmarked a particular post that was bookmarked by a certain user. In that way you can take a particular user's bookmark and find the other users who also bookmarked that post. That might be an easy way to do something like:

```
@bookmark.post.users.count
```

This could be used in say, a list of a user's bookmarks, to tell them how many other people also bookmarked that same post.

Remember, you don't "need" any associations. The are just giving you a bunch of queries as methods. It's mostly "sugar". You could get by without them, but then you'd have to write all those methods yourself.