# How to create seeds of a polymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism

I have three objects:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable  
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end
```

How should I create test seed data, to associate an image with both a seed employee and seed product ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to associate an image with **both** a seed employee and seed product

This would require a `many-to-many` relationship (either `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through`):

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
  has_many :pictures, through: :images
end

#app/models/employee.rb
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
  has_many :pictures, through: :images
end

#app/models/image.rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :picture
end

#app/models/picture.rb
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end
```

This would allow you to use:

```
#db/seed.rb
@employee = Employee.find_or_create_by x: "y"
@picture  = @employee.pictures.find_or_create_by file: x

@product = Product.find_or_create_by x: "y"
@product.pictures << @picture
```

[ActiveRecord, has_many :through, and Polymorphic Associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683265/activerecord-has-many-through-and-polymorphic-associations)

---

Because you're using a `polymorphic` relationship, you won't be able to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

The above will set the polymorphism on the `join` table; each `Picture` being "naked" (without a "creator"). Some hacking would be required to define the original creator of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Create them from the `has_many` end instead:

```
employee = Employee.create! fields: 'values'
employee.pictures.create! fields: 'values'

product = Product.create! fields: 'values'
product.pictures.create! fields: 'values'
```

Although just one quick note: when seeding, you may already have the data you want in the database, so I would use `instance = Model.where(find_by: 'values').first_or_create(create_with: 'values')` instead.

NB. I've just noticed: you're not trying to associate *one* image with *multiple* owners, are you? Because each image only belongs to one `Imageable`, and that is *either* an `Employee` or a `Product`. If you want to do that, you'll have to set up a many-to-many join.

Comment: Right. Do `Employee`s and `Product`s *need* many pictures? (If so then ignore this comment, but) if not, you could just reverse the join - put the foreign keys to `picture` on those tables - and then you can just have two `has_many`s on the `Picture` side, with no need for them to be polymorphic.